# Using JOIN when second record might not exist

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm dealing with two tables - `users` with about 20 million rows, and `data` with about 2 billion rows.

I need to select all `users` rows where `active=1`, and then join that with their corresponding `data` row where `users.username=data.username` AND `data.date='2017-11-30'`.

The catch is that many of these users won't have a `data` row where `date='2017-11-30'`, but I still need their record to be returned, just without any info for that date.

What would be the most resource-efficient way to accomplish this? I got a start with this, but it doesn't look quite right:

`SELECT users.username FROM users
INNER JOIN data ON data.username = users.username
WHERE
users.active = 1 AND data.date = ‘2017-11-30’`

Comment: You might like to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Comment: Inner join requires records in both tables. Left join only in the first table.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can just do a left join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN data 
  ON data.username = users.username AND data.date = '2017-11-30'
WHERE
users.active = 1
```